# Add Civilcrm member detail in third party tcexam

Tags: drupal, webform-civicrm

I was working in a drupal civicrm. I made a contribution for the course and succeed in a payment, but I have to update the data in the third party like tcexam. Is there a way that we can add a member details in the tcexam after success payment process in civicrm.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand your question.  Could you please edit it to provide more detail.  Perhaps you could explain what 'tcexam' is.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this, but you need to be a programmer, or hire one.

CiviCRM is well suited to this, TCExam is not because it has no API.  If they both live on the same server, that's not too bad though.

Write an extension for CiviCRM that uses [hook_civicrm_post](https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/hook_civicrm_post).  When a completed contribution is added, make a connection to TCExam's SQL database and insert a new user record.

Instructions for writing an extension are available [here](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/master/extensions/basics/) and [here](https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Create+a+Module+Extension).